# Dynamodb insertion efficiency depending on the type of the input + impact on the pricing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am doing some tests with dynamodb in local and I have seen a behaviour that I can't explain that leads to a particular question. For the context, I was doing my tests with the nodejs SDK V3 using DynamoDBDocumentClient (an utility that will convert javascript object to dynamodb attributes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html).

So I simply noticed in local that when I was calling PutItem with a list of map it was a lot faster (300ms) than when calling with a map of list (4s).
List of map (case 1):

```js
{
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "Element1": {
            "L": [
              {
                "S": "1"
              },
              {
                "N": "1660964494"
              },
              {
                "S": "1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }, //... more elements continuing here
```

Map of list (case 2):

```js
{
    "M": {
      "Element1": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "1"
          },
          {
            "N": "1660964550"
          },
          {
            "S": "1"
          }
        ]
      },// More and more elements after that...
```

Also, as expected, depending on the structure of the datas the request will cost more or less capacityUnits. In local for my datas I have:
case 1 => 176 CapacityUnits
case 2 => 138 CapacityUnits

However since case 1 seems a lot faster than case 2 in local (maybe because of the way dynamodb is storing List and maps) I would like to know if it will be better to use case 2 since it will use less capacityUnits so it means I will pay less I guess.
Maybe case 1 is better because there is a cost in dynamodb for the speed of the request? (can't find any documentation on this)

Or maybe it's just a behaviour in local and the speed doesn't correlate with production dynamodb?

Comment: My suggestion is that you pick the data model that best supports your expected access patterns. Also, I wouldn't measure against DynamoDB Local because its results may not be representative of the actual DynamoDB service.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Out of curiosity I will test it in production but it appears a bit strange to me that a request costing less CapacityUnits can take more execution time that the other.

Answer (score 1):

A *write capacity unit* is 1 KB, suggesting that your list-of-maps and map-of-lists have slightly different lengths - 176 KB vs 138 KB. I don't think it's surprising, even in your example the first example seems a little bit longer. It's not a big difference... But obviously the shorter version has the advantage that it will cost you less to write, store, and finally read. However, I suggest that you measure this on the actual DynamoDB, **not** on DynamoDB Local which isn't guaranteed to be identical to DynamoDB.

However, you should also keep in mind that having very large items is not a good idea in DynamoDB. There is a hard limit of 400 KB which your 176 KB example comes pretty close to reaching, so if your use case grows a bit it will exceed this hard limit. Also, every read of the 176 KB item will need to read its entirety, and every modification to a small piece will need to re-write the entire 176 KB, costing you a lot.

Instead, an third alternative you can consider instead of a list is a **partition**: A partition can have multiple items (identified with different sort keys), so instead of a list you can keep the list of items in a partition. This will allow you to read or modify an individual item without paying for reading or writing the entire list - but will also allow you to read the entire list (the partition) when you want to.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure it is what you are saying with partition but I figured out I can redesign my system to split those big items into multiple items. However I have one other issue, I need to frequently update or add new of those items so it will result in many write operations and I don't know how to avoid it.
I can read it easily using sort key or LSI but still need to write and update a lot of items at once.

Comment: A "partition" is many items which share the same "partition key" and differ by the value of their "sort key". Instead of having a "list" of values, you can have a partition and each value will be in a separate item. Anyway, DynamoDB prices writes according to their length so a 100KB write will cost the same as 100 writes of 1KB each. You're write that doing tiny writes (less than 1KB each) will cost you too much.